# TCPDF: What is the best approach for having different font-styles in one MultiCell?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm trying to create a PDF with TCPDF (www.tcpdf.com) and have some problems how I could achieve a Cell with a heading and content.

There's the possibility of using HTML within a cell, or I could use 2 cells which are stacked above.

Or do I have a chance in using SetFont for the different contents in the cell?

Also: If someone would know how to do a rowspan with a MultiCell I would really appreciate it. Now If I'm making a bigger cell it pushes everything down under away (they would never collide because the rowspan-cell is far more right than the other cells.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use WriteHTMLcell() instead and use XHTML code. In this way you can change font, style, colors, and many other things.
Check the example n. 1 at http://www.tcpdf.org for further information.